# How can I overlay two images of people of different sizes and aspect ratios if I have body part coordinates?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, mediapipe

I have two images of people(one person each picture), and I want to overlap them as best I can so that they are roughly the same size in the frame and their hips or shoulders overlap.

For example say each image has a person mostly straight, except one is sitting and the other is standing, and one is to the left of the frame, and the other in the middle. **How can I recreate the images so they are both lined up at the shoulders and sized similarly?**

Lets say the dimensions are:
pic1 is `430x250`
pic2 is `230x320`

and I have the coordinates for both of their bodyparts stored as a dictionary like this:

```
"keypoints": [ // keypoints for the first picture...
            {
                "part": "nose",
                "x": 235, // x coordinate in the pic
                "y": 150 // y coordinate in the pic
                
            },
            {
                "part": "leftEye",
                "x": 239,
                "y": 148
            },
```

... and so on for all the major bodyparts, for BOTH images

So given that the the person in each image can stand in a different way, and the images are not the same sizes how can I best overlap the two images in most cases so that they both look like they are overlapping?

Comment: 1) Can you explain on what do you mean recreate the images? Do you want to move person in A to image B. Or person in B to A. Or superimpose the image? Or Take A and B and put in image C? Secondly, why not use a photo editor? (cropping can be done quite easily).  On your last line. You could just make a big blank image. Put A into the image center. Put B such that the mean squared error between all your keypoints is minimum.

Comment: @JasonChia I want to take image A and from it create image A' that has the person within image A in the center now in A'. The same for image B, make B` the person in B now in the center. Now if I overlay A' and B' the shoulders and hips should be in roughly the same spots. I have to do this for tens of thousands of images so a photo editor wont work. I thought about using a big blank image but ran into issues doing it with numpy, I also have to scale the people so they're roughly the same size

Comment: So you want the two images overlayed on top of each other in the final output? Or A' and B' altered such that the desired keypoints are matched as close as possible but in two separate images?

Comment: @Jason The second, where A' and B' are altered so that they match but are separate images

Comment: What you would be looking at would be to scale the x/y distance between each of your marker points. You can select the most 'important' ones and make a simple algorithm to use the cv2.resize function. I.e. make the distance between the nose and the waist of the body match would set vertical scaling, and making the distance between the left and right shoulder would set it for x.